# Can't run a python file in Jenkins execute shell

Tags: python, git, shell, jenkins

I found a problem running a python file in Jenkins execute shell, which I successfully run in my Ubuntu terminal. 
Could you please tell me what the problem is? Thank you!

When I try this in the execute shell box:

**cd /home/anna/workspace/gitinspector/gitinspector**

**gitinspector --format=html /home/anna/workspace/parser > /home/anna/workspace/report08.html**

It tells me gitinspector not found.

When I try this in the execute shell box:

**cd /home/anna/workspace/gitinspector/gitinspector**

**python gitinspector.py --format=html /home/anna/workspace/parser > /home/anna/workspace/report08.html**

It tells me there are errors inside the gitinspector.py file.

Thank you!

Comment: In the first case the message indicates that the folder containing an executable `gitinspector` is not in the current `PATH` variable - try `./gitinspector.py` instead. In the second case - what are the errors you get?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added gitinspetor to PATH, it gives me this error message no matter i use `./gitinspector.py` or the second case: `
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: must be string, not None
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE`

Answer (score 0):

**Use absolute path** when running python or any other program through Jenkins **OR** you need to **set environment variable** for `PATH`. So, you can run the following command to get the desired result:

```
 <location of python>/python <location of gitinspector>/gitinspector.py --format=html 
 /home/anna/workspace/parser > /home/anna/workspace/report08.html
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried to set environment variable and add the locations, but it still gives me error message ended with: `Traceback (most recent call last): TypeError: must be string, not None Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE`

Comment: Did you try the command with absolute path of python and gitinspector in the command ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really tried the absolute path (if this is right: '/usr/bin/python'), but it still tells me error in the py file. But, I succeeded by doing it in windows, with one more line: 'set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8'. Thank you again.